# how to fully rename all folders and files of a visual studio project?

Tags: visual-studio, rename, projects-and-solutions

So I copied a project, and change the name at every place I could find, but at one place I cant change the name without destroying the project.

So in the folder "TestName" I got another folder "TestName" and the solution "TestName.sln"
When I apply the name changes, I get already so far that the solution is now "NewName.sln" and everything inside NewName\TestName\ is using the new name.

But I cant find the place where I can change the subfolder "TestName" into "NewName".
If I try it manually, the project will not load anymore, because it is still referencing the path NewName\TestName instead of NewName\NewName

So either I need to change the used path or I need an "official" way to change the subfolders name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After renaming the project directory, you need to change the path to the project file in the solution file.

For example:

```
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "DE.Currency", "DE.Currency\DE.Currency.csproj", "{4DE44F2B-32BF-4CCA-A2CA-248828CA2BF3}"
EndProject
```

To rename the `DE.Currency` project to `DE.NewProjectName` you would rename the directory `DE.Currency` to `DE.NewProjectName`, and then within that directory, rename `DE.Currency.csproj` to `DE.NewProjectName.csproj`. Then you would edit the solution file to point to the path of the project file:

```
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "DE.NewProjectName", "DE.NewProjectName\DE.NewProject.csproj", "{4DE44F2B-32BF-4CCA-A2CA-248828CA2BF3}"
EndProject
```

NOTE that there are 3 places in the solution file that refer to the old project name that must be changed, the project's "friendly" name, the directory that contains the project, and the actual name of the project file.

If you have other projects in the same solution that reference that renamed project, you will have to edit their csproj files also, to update the project references.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\DE.NewProjectName\DE.NewProjectName.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

You should do all of this with the solution closed out of Visual Studio, or it will get VERY confused.

There are probably MANY other places in your code that you will want to update, including the assembly name, resources, and namespaces, if you want everything to be consistent.

Comment: Thank you, I looked literally everywhere but never considered manually editing the .sln... At first the project still wouldnt load, so I copied the old folder back, then it did load then I deleted the old folder, and now seems to work fine.